# Quickblox - fetch user friends' avatars and display inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, quickblox, avatar

I need to display entire friend list's avatar images inside UITableView.

I could as well ask this into Quickblox forums but seems like their support is less responsive there.

I have read Quickblox documentation but can't find an efficient way of getting user's avatar images. All I see is `[QBContent TDownloadFileWithBlobID]`, but I do not know how to use it.

I am fetching contacts using `chatContactListDidChange` delegate call like below. Now how can I also get all these users' avatar images also?

Note that friendsArray is my data source for the table view, so ideally I would want to store the avatar images as part of the same array.

```
- (void)chatContactListDidChange:(QBContactList *)contactList
{
    NSLog(@"contact list changed");
    NSLog(@"current contact list %@", [QBChat instance].contactList);
    [self fetchContacts:[QBChat instance].contactList.contacts];
}

- (void) fetchContacts : (NSArray *) contactArray
{
    NSMutableArray * userIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (QBContactListItem * contact in contactArray)
    {
        NSString * userIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)contact.userID];
        [userIDArray addObject:userIDString];
    }

    if (!userIDArray.count)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString * requestString = [userIDArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    [QBUsers usersWithIDs:requestString delegate:self context:@"FetchFriends"];
}

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result context:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if([result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserPagedResult class]])
    {
        NSString * context = (__bridge NSString *)contextInfo;
        // Success result
        if(result.success)
        {
            QBUUserPagedResult * pagedResult = (QBUUserPagedResult *)result;
            if ([context isEqualToString:@"FetchFriends"])
            {
                if (friendsArray)
                {
                    [friendsArray removeAllObjects];
                }
                else
                {
                    friendsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }

                QBUUser * user = [pagedResult.users objectAtIndex:0];
                //user.blobID   
                friendsArray addObjectsFromArray:pagedResult.users];
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error getting users: %@", context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use QBUUser's fields - **customData** for public url of user's image and **blobID** for uploaded blob.

Image --> [QBContent TUploadFile...] --> Getting callback with result (QBCFileUploadTaskResult) --> getting blob (QBCBlob) --> save blob id to user.blobID --> get public url of your image: [currentBlob  publicURL] --> save to user.customData --> update user: [QBUsers updateUser...]
Hope it helps you.